# Question about chips

Tags: support

I'd like to post a question about a specific computer chip.

I have a tiny piece of hardware that has been presented as being a chip with embedded information.
I think it's actually just a contact to enable a counter and would like other opinions?

Is this the place to post this kind of question?
If not, where?

Comment: I'm inclined to say it would be a better fit for [electronics.se]. Also I was going to make a joke about wanting a fish with my chips but it was too awkward.

Comment: I was going to say that but It really feels like we need more information to make an informed suggestions

Comment: This is the text without image
________________________________________
I reload ink in a Canon Pro 1 and part of the reload process is to change the chip on the cartridge. Although the supplier says the chips are specific to the ink color, the supplied pieces all seem to be physically the same, to be only contacts and are quite simple. Here is a picture of a typical 'chip'. Are these just contacts to enable the counter for each color or is it plausible that these are actually coded with some information?

Comment: The question as written is not clear.  So it wouldn't be appropriate anywhere at this point.

Comment: there is an image that goes with this but I didn't post it here?

Comment: What is the context of this question? Are you trying to reverse engineer an ink cartridge or use cartridges that look similar but are marketed for a different printer? Further, the question isn't really answerable. Canon controls the chip and has probably not published any specific information about it. Additionally, all that you normally see in a chip is the contacts, making that part of your argument irrelevant.